# How can I debug TypeScript code (.tsx files) running in a CEFSharp browser control using Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-debugging, cefsharp

We are building a desktop app that run a React-based web app inside a CEFSharp browser window. The web app is written in TypeScript, using .tsx files for the React-based GUI components.

When I open the devtools for the CEFSharp, I can see and open .ts (and the transpiled .js)  source code files, and I can set breakpoints too.

--> However, for my React components I can see the .tsx files in the source files list, but when I click on them, an empty file shows up in the devtools (so obviously, I can't put breakpoints in the code...) The .map files are present.

Note that when I run the web app outside of a CEFBRowser (not in a desktop application), I can perfectly debug also the .tsx files in Chrome's devtools.

I have 2 Visual Studio solutions: one for the desktop application (a WinForms app), and another one for the web app (a TypeScript/React app).
The desktop app is coded to start a new process for IIS Express and load the web app page that was previously compiled to an output folder. The CEFSharp browser is created somewhere in the desktop app and opens the http://localhost:port page to show the web app in the desktop app.

So:

1. Is not being able to debug .tsx files a limitation of the devtools coming with CEFSharp?
2. Is there a way to attach a Visual Studio debugger to the web app running in the  CEFSharp browser (so I can debug with Visual Studio instead)? Which process should I attach to?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Koen

Comment: See https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16182

Comment: Thanks @amaitland for the reply and the link. But I believe my issue is a different one: I do see the .ts files, that's all fine. As stated, the issue is that I don't see the .tsx files for my React components...

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem using version  75.1.142 then ask on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php likely tsx files aren't supported by CEF currently.

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply. I'll check my version and if I can reproduce with 75.1.142, I'll do as you say.

Comment: @KoenT_X did you find a solution?